# polygon porjection to another crs and backwards to original crs results in different polygon

Tags: python, shapely, pyproj

I'm trying to place a 50km buffer on each country in the world. For this I transform the country shapes from epsg:4326 to Lambert azimuthal equal-area(laea), apply a buffer to it and then transform it back to espg:4326. This works well for the most of the countries but for russia the inverse transformation results in some projection error:

This is my Code and the resulting shapes:

```
    center =centroid(border)
    plot(to_shapely(border),'border.png')
    proj_str = "+proj=laea +lat_0=" + str(center.y) + " +lon_0=" + str(
            center.x) + " +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs"
    project = pyproj.Transformer.from_proj(pyproj.Proj('epsg:4326'),pyproj.Proj(proj_str),always_xy=True)
    project2 = pyproj.Transformer.from_proj(pyproj.Proj(proj_str),pyproj.Proj('epsg:4326'),always_xy=True)
    plot(transform(project2.transform,transform(project.transform, shapely.wkt.loads(geometry))),'backtrans.png')
```

[image: origin shape]

[image: shape after inverse transformation]

Does anyone has a suggestion what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't found a inhouse solution for this problem, so i implemented a function which should do the work.

First, I had to change the proj String and add +over to it, so the polygon doesn't get wrapped at the map border. Then i split the Polygons at the Map Border and Wrap the Polygons out side of the map to the other side. Here is the Code Snippet, it works for Russia.

```
        import pyproj
        from shapely.ops import transform
        from pygeos import Geometry, centroid,to_shapely, from_shapely,buffer,union,symmetric_difference, is_valid,make_valid,box, intersection, difference,apply
        proj_str = "+proj=laea +lat_0=" + str(center.y) + " +lon_0=" + str(
            center.x) + " +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs +over"
        project = pyproj.Transformer.from_proj(pyproj.Proj('epsg:4326'),pyproj.Proj(proj_str),always_xy=True)
        border= from_shapely(transform(project.transform, to_shapely(border)))
        if not is_valid(border):
            border = make_valid(border)
        project = pyproj.Transformer.from_proj(pyproj.Proj(proj_str),pyproj.Proj('epsg:4326'),always_xy=True)
        border_buffer = from_shapely(transform(project.transform, to_shapely(border_buffer)))
        map_border=box(-180,-90,180,90)
        geometry_out_of_map = difference(border_buffer,map_border)
        geometry_wrap=apply(geometry_out_of_map,lambda x: ((x+[180,90])%[360,180])+[-180,-90])
        geometry_in_map = intersection(border_buffer,map_border)
        border_buffer= union(geometry_in_map,geometry_wrap)
```

I'm sure there's a much cleaner way, but I think it works (at least for my spicific problem, where polygons only cross the map at one side).

Instead of pygeos it's possible to only use shapely. I only used shapely for transformation becouse I couldn't find a method for this purpose in pygeos.